# Outputting XML structure using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to dynamically output data from an XML file using XSLT. We have a few different structures of data and rather than have to explicitly loop through each section I was wondering if there is a way to do it in one block of code. This is an example of the XML I will receive:

```
        <IntermediaryInfo>
            <PersonalInformation>
                <Title>str1234</Title>
                <FirstName>str1234</FirstName>
                <Surname>str1234</Surname>
                <DateofBirth>2012-12-13</DateofBirth>
                <WorkTelephoneNumber>str1234</WorkTelephoneNumber>
            </PersonalInformation>
            <CompanyInformation>
                <CompanyName>str1234</CompanyName>
                <CompanyFCANumber>str1234</CompanyFCANumber>
            </CompanyInformation>
            <CompanyAddress>
                <PostCode>str1234</PostCode>
                <HouseNumber>str1234</HouseNumber>
                <HouseName>str1234</HouseName>
                <AddressLine1>str1234</AddressLine1>
                <AddressLine2>str1234</AddressLine2>
            </CompanyAddress>
            <CompanyPermissionLevels>
                <AdvisingonConsumer>str1234</AdvisingonConsumer>
                <ArrangingConsumerBuytoLetmortgageContracts>str1234</ArrangingConsumerBuytoLetmortgageContracts>
            </CompanyPermissionLevels>
            <PrincipleFirm>
                <FirmName>str1234</FirmName>
                <FirmFCANumber>123</FirmFCANumber>
            </PrincipleFirm>
            <LendingPartner>str1234</LendingPartner>
        </IntermediaryInfo>
```

Is there a way to loop through each node and output the node name and value using XSLT? So it would look something like this:

```
    PersonalInformation
    -------------------
    Title: str1234
    FirstName: str1234
    Surname: str1234
    DateofBirth: 2012-12-13
    WorkTelephoneNumber: str1234

    CompanyInformation
    ------------------
    CompanyName: str1234
    CompanyFCANumber: str1234
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You need to provide specific rules for such transformation. For example, how should `LendingPartner` be presented in the output? What if there are other sections that have a deeper hierarchy than the one shown here?

Comment: Are you producing formatted PDF using XSL-FO or just producing text?  If just text, the 'xsl-fo' tag needn't apply.

Comment: There is no deeper hierarchy and LendingPartner would just be output the same as the rest like LendingPartner: str1234. It is just text, apologies, I will remove the xsl-fo tag.

Comment: "*LendingPartner would just be output the same as the rest*" But under what heading?

Comment: Oh right sorry, it would not have a heading, any tags without a parent would just be output as the heading itself as it looks within your answer below.

Comment: Is your question answered then?

Comment: I think so, but lastly if I wanted to test for the existence of the <IntermediaryInfo> tag before applying the template matching, do you know of the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you could use as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent" />
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="indent" select="concat($indent, '&#9;')"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[text()]">
    <xsl:param name="indent"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$indent" />
    <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
    <xsl:text>: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
IntermediaryInfo
    PersonalInformation
        Title: str1234
        FirstName: str1234
        Surname: str1234
        DateofBirth: 2012-12-13
        WorkTelephoneNumber: str1234
    CompanyInformation
        CompanyName: str1234
        CompanyFCANumber: str1234
    CompanyAddress
        PostCode: str1234
        HouseNumber: str1234
        HouseName: str1234
        AddressLine1: str1234
        AddressLine2: str1234
    CompanyPermissionLevels
        AdvisingonConsumer: str1234
        ArrangingConsumerBuytoLetmortgageContracts: str1234
    PrincipleFirm
        FirmName: str1234
        FirmFCANumber: 123
    LendingPartner: str1234
```